# Remove Wordpress body classes on search page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm seeing a lot of guides on how to add more classes to a Wordpress body tag, but is there a way to remove all classes from a specific page template, more specifically the search page?

Here's where I'm at so far.. not much sorry.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'remove_search_class');
function remove_search_class($classes){

global $post;

if(is_search()) {
    // find ".search & .search-results"
    }

    return // no classes within <body>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter('body_class','alter_search_classes');
function alter_search_classes($classes) {
    if(is_search()){
       return array();
    } else {
       return $classes;
    }

}
```

**try adding this in your functions.php**